# declaring structs in c with a struct inside a struct

Tags: c, struct

I am new to c programming I am trying to understand structs concept in c
in many tutorial they explained how to declare structs with this below example

```
 struct node
    {
      int data;
      int value;
    }
```

I under stand the above case ,but in the case below case they declared a struct inside it

```
 struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;  \\ what is this?  why they declared like it ?
}
```

Comment: Thats not a nested struct. The last member of the struct `node` is a *pointer* to a type of `struct node`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested structure in C is nothing but structure within structure. One structure can be declared inside other structure as we declare structure members inside a structure. The structure variables can be a normal structure variable or a pointer variable to access the data.

Here's some statements about nested structures:

- Structure written inside another structure is called as nesting of two structures.
- Nested Structures are allowed in C Programming Language.
- We can write one Structure inside another structure as member of another structure.

Also you might need to use "forward declaration" of `node` before.

Here's a good explanation and example are given: [Nested struct in C language](https://fresh2refresh.com/c/c-nested-structure/)